# Windows 10 Audio stopped working. I've tried all obvious solutions

Tags: windows-10, audio

I am on a Windows 10 machine w Nvidia 1080 and Realtek Audio sound card.

I had 6 tabs of Firefox open, 1 tab of Chrome open, with a video playing from youtube in one of the Firefox tabs. I doubt this is relevant, but this is my everyday use and nothing out of the ordinary was occurring when the audio went out. It simply stopped in the middle of a news stream. The audio, not the video.

My first step was to restart; and I, of course, restart after every attempted solution.

"Troubleshooting" the problem via right click on the task bar audio menu, says the Audio Service is not responding. Windows automatically restarts the service, in this situation, but it does not restore sound.

I went into services and restarted the audio services, myself, but this also had no effect. I made a second attempt to do this through the command line. While the service is still "Running", it does not seem to be working properly.

I have uninstalled the drivers and reinstalled them via the Device Properties section. This includes the High Definition Audio, Realtek drivers and Nvidia High Definition audio drivers.

I have restored to an older system restore point, which was ineffective. Then, again, reinstalled the drivers.

I have taken ownership of the System32 folder and manually replaced the driver files.

I have uninstalled every ancillary device. I have stopped every ancillary service.

When I attempt to play a test sound, it gives me a message that the test sound has failed. This is true for all audio devices; speakers, HDMI out, headphones (both 1/8inch jack and Bluetooth). Even on different audio outputs, I have the same problem.

When I plug in headphones, Realtek serves up the menu to select options and play a test sound. The test sound does not play. When I am plugged into a TV via HDMI, I still have the same "Audio Service not responding message".

I went into the event log and found where it logged that the audio services terminated unexpectedly, but no other accompanying information came with it.

I went into the BIOS menu and made sure the sound was enabled.

I'm out of ideas. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am a musician and I have been recording music every day for years. I have never had a problem, until now. I'm kind of desperate, really. I have never encountered an audio problem I couldn't fix myself in like 20 years.

Thank you for any suggestions. I will try anything, at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I did finally manage to fix this on my own my manually uninstalling every single Windows update, then updated Windows.

I have a Linux partition on the computer where the sound works fine, confirming it wasn't the hardware.

I couldn't say exactly what the problem was, but rolling Windows back and reinstalling all updates did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution for anyone coming across this, though this issue sounds slightly different than the one I had (having the audio service not responding).

If the following registry entry is currently set to a "zero-length binary value", either change it manually or save the following as `fixaudio.reg` and import it, then reboot.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations]
"ConsoleSecurity"=hex:01,00,14,80,9c,00,00,00,a8,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,00,\
  00,02,00,88,00,06,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,01,00,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,\
  04,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,bf,03,0f,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,12,00,00,00,00,\
  00,14,00,89,00,0f,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,13,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,81,00,\
  00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,14,00,00,00,00,00,18,00,bf,03,0f,00,01,02,00,\
  00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,00,00,18,00,21,01,00,00,01,02,00,00,\
  00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,2b,02,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,12,00,00,00,01,\
  01,00,00,00,00,00,05,12,00,00,00
```

See https://superuser.com/a/1697593 for a bit more detail.